# Getting selectedrow in RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, buttonfield

i have a gridview as:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvOpinions" runat="server" Width="100%" CellPadding="4" 
                        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="100px" Visible="False" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowcommand="gdvOpinions_RowCommand" >
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Confirm" Text="تائید" />
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" Text="حذف" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="مقاله" HeaderText="مقاله" >
                        <ControlStyle Width="150px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="نظر کاربر" HeaderText="نظر کاربر" >
                        <ControlStyle Width="250px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

As you see, i have two buttonfield for every row, but when i click one of these buttons and want to get their row in

```
gdvOpinions_RowCommand
```

the

```
gdvOpinions.SelectedRow
```

returns null;
how should i find which row is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" 
    OnRowCommand = "OnRowCommand">
 <Columns>
  <asp:ButtonField CommandName = "ButtonField"  DataTextField = "CustomerID"
        ButtonType = "Button"/>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[index]; 
}
```

Comment: Clicking buttonfield doesn't fire `SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: thanks, that's exactly the problem i'm talking about with @HarveySpecter

Comment: @SalehRezaei  you can use OnRowCommand event to get current row..see my edited ans..

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand out of your question, if you are trying to get the row for which the button was clicked, then in that case this might be the right thing to do :

```
GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
```

Now here, this is for a control such as a `Button` or `ImageButton`. You might have to improvise on this for `ButtonField`.

You can also change the `ButtonField` to a simple `TemplateField` with a `Button`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Remove `.NamingContainer` and try.

Comment: it returns:    Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'

Comment: Change you `ButtonField` to a `TemplateField` with a Button. That should do it.